# Multiple thread accessing same data but getting latest data?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote this program:

```
package com.example.threads;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ConcurrentHashMapBehaviour {

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static Object _lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
        t.start();

        int counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            String val = "FirstVal" + counter;
            counter++;
            String currentVal = null;
            synchronized (_lock) {
                chm.put("first", val);
                currentVal = chm.get("first");
            }
            System.out.println("In Main thread, current value is : " + currentVal);
        }
    }

    static class MyThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String val = null;
            while (true) {
                synchronized (_lock) {
                    val = chm.get("first");
                }
                System.out.println("Value seen in MyThread is " + val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sharing a common data between these thread viz: `chm` (ConcurrentHashMap). I made this to run in debug mode in which I made `Main thread` run more times than `MyThread`, both are controlled by `_lock`.

So, for instance, I made to run `Main thread` twice and so the value of "first" key would be "FirstVal1". Then i made `Main Thread` to halt and made `MyThread` to proceed, it was able to get the latest value, even though main thread was run multiple times.

How is this possible? I was under the impression that this variable needs to be `volatile` in order for these `MyThread` to get the latest values.

I didn't understand this behaviour. Can anyone decipher this where I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're using a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which is safe to use in a multi-threaded environment, so if a thread puts a value into it, other threads will be able to see that value.

Second, you are synchronizing access to the map. That will ensure only one thread will write to the map.

Each such explicit synchronization also includes a memory-barrier, which will write any results waiting in a cache to be written to the main memory, making it possible for other threads to see it. Which is what a volatile variable access is: access to volatile values have memory visibility guarantees.

If you want to see data races in your program, remove all synchronization primitives and try again. That does not guarantee that you'll observe a race all the time, but you should be able to see unexpected values every now and then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified my program , removed synchronization block and instead using `ConcurrentHashMap` used a plain `int data` variable and controlled the flow (giving main thread more chance so that it increments it more often). However, latest values are availabe in other thread. Has it to do anything with static qualifier? Or as per `Bjorn Zurmaar` (below answer), JVM might make latest value available without it being `volatile`.

Comment: `volatile` guarantees visibility. Without `volatile` there is no guarantee that you'll see the latest values. That doesn't mean you'll not see the latest values. It only means you may sometimes see stale values. That's why data races are so hard to debug.

Comment: That is also the reason sometimes using another or an updated JVM "breaks" your seemingly correct implementation. Because the new / other JVM is not as forgiving as the other but still strictly in accordance to the JLS and reveals an error in your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any material that you suggest for better understanding. I know this topic is difficult to understand, however, want to know somewhat better what I currently know. For example, i wasn't aware of "memory-barrier", so can you please suggest any further reading. Do i need to know the "memory model" of Java program to know all this?

Comment: Java langauge specification threads section is the definitive reference. It also includes the memory model. Being familiar with the memory model helps explain some behaviors that might otherwise be counterintuitive.

Comment: You do need to know the java memory model, at least the basics. I recommend "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz. Also [here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) is an excellent article by Jeremy Manson about the volatile keyword.

Answer (score 1):

There are three misconceptions here:

1. Writing to a volatile variable guarantees that all changes made by the writing thread are published, i.e. can be seen by other threads. See [The Java Language Specification Chapter 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) for all the details. This does not mean that the absence of the volatile modifier forbids publication. JVM implementations may be (and actually are) implemented much more forgiving. This is one of the reasons concurrency problems are so hard to trace.
2. "A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and high expected concurrency for updates." is the first sentence of the [API Documentation on the ConcurrentHashMap class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). And that pretty much sums it up. The concurrent hashmap guarantees that when calling get any thread gets the latest value. That's exactly the purpose of this class. If you look at its source code you can by the way see that they use volatile fields internally.
3. You're additionally using synchronized blocks to access your data. These do not only guarantee exclusive access, they also guarantee that all changes made before leaving such a block are visible to all threads that synchronize on the same lock object.

To summarize it: By using the concurrent hashmap implementation and using synchronization blocks you publish the changes and make the latest changes visible to other threads. One of the two would have already been sufficient.